# Are the below time complexities asymptotically same?

Tags: algorithm

If I have Omega(1) , theta(1) and Big O(1) are these asymptotically same ,if not then whats the difference among all these ?

Comment: In simple terms, Omega(1) will not take less than 1 unit time, BigO(1) will not take more than 1 unit time and Theta(1) will take time proportional to 1 unit time.

Comment: So that means all are different ?

Comment: Well, yes. They are three different complexity classes. Big O is used to develop upper bounds; Big Omega is used to develop lower bounds; and Big Theta is used to classify algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

`f(x) = O(g(x))` (big-oh) means that the growth rate of `f(x)` is asymptotically **less than or equal to** to the growth rate of `g(x)`.

`f(x) = Ω(g(x))` (big-omega) means that the growth rate of `f(x)` is asymptotically **greater than or equal to** the growth rate of `g(x)`

`f(x) = o(g(x))` (small-oh) means that the growth rate of `f(x)` is asymptotically **less than** the growth rate of `g(x)`.

`f(x) = ω(g(x))` (small-omega) means that the growth rate of `f(x)` is asymptotically **greater than** the growth rate of `g(x)`

`f(x) = Θ(g(x))` (theta) means that the growth rate of `f(x)` is asymptotically **equal to** the growth rate of `g(x)`

Comment: But according to me it should be that Big-oh(1) and theta(1) should be same while omega(1) should be different